# Undefined property: App\User::$login using Jenssegers\Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I am having troubles to relate two `classes` using `Laravel 5.5` and `Jenssegers\Mongodb`.

Here is my User `class`:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use App\Login;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Usuario extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'user';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'nickname', 'date_birth', 'gender', 'login',
    ];

     public function login(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Login::class, 'login');
    }

}
```

And here is my Login `class`:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use App\User;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Login extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'login';

    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'login');
    }   
}
```

On UserController, I defined index method like this:

```
public function index()
{
    try {

    $user= User::with('login')->get();

    return response()->json(['users' => $user], 200);

    } catch(Exception $e) {
       throw new Exception($e);
    }
}
```

When I `POST` an user with a login to store `method`, it works well. However, when I call `GET`, I get this message:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined property: App\User::$login

On `laravel.log`, it has:

> [2018-12-12 13:05:42] local.ERROR: Undefined property:
>   App\User::$login {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0):
>   Undefined property: App\User::$login at
>   [project-path]\vendor\jenssegers\mongodb\src\Jenssegers\Mongodb\Relations\BelongsTo.php:28)
>   [stacktrace]

I already tried to put

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Relations\HasOne;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Relations\HasMany;
```

on the top of each `class`, however it doesnt work either.

When I call `User::all();` on `controller`, I get the users with the id of login `object`:

```
{
   "users": [
              {
                 "_id": "5c10ed8bc557ab2ed0007034",
                 "name": "test user",
                 "login": "5c10ed8bc557ab2ed0007033",
                 //other fields
              }
           ]
}
```

But I want to get it like this:

```
{
   "users": [
              {
                 "_id": "5c10ed8bc557ab2ed0007034",
                 "name": "test user",
                 "login": {
                              "_id": "5c10ed8bc557ab2ed0007033",
                              "email": "some@email",
                              "password": "somepwd"
                          },
                 //other fields
              }
           ]
}
```

I think it's a problem with `Jenssegers\Mongodb`, because I used this project on a `MySQL database` and now I am migrating it to `MongoDB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `controller` I manipulated both `classes` separately, like this:

```
public function index()
{
    try {

    $users = User::all();

    $userslogin = array();
    foreach ($users as $usr) {
        $login = Login::find($usr)->first();
        $usr->login = $login;
        $userslogin[] = $usr;
    }

    return response()->json(['usuario' => $usuarios], 200);

    } catch(Exception $e) {
       throw new Exception($e);
    }
}
```

If someone have another solution, I will be thankful to read it.